# How to create texture for Displacement Modifier to rise a flat grid into mountains?

Tags: displacement

I want to rise a flat grid into something like below

[image]

The displacement modifier seems to be what I am looking for.
This is my first time using Blender.

Question is: how to make a texture for mountains?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.